# sed with literal string ( sed: no input files )

Tags: linux, unix

This should be easy: I want to run sed against a literal string, not an input file. If you wonder why, it is to, for example edit values stored in variables, not necessarily text data.

When I do:

```
cat getGCC_MSISDN.tsk | sed -i 's/TEMP_MSISDN/'$1'/g' | java_gcc_soap_any.ksh
```

What should be the correct command? I want it to take my MSIDN from the file.

Comment: Using `-i` when you are not reading from a regular file is unwise.

Answer (score 0):

Use `printf` to print the literal string.

```
printf '%s\n' 'some_literal_string' | sed 's/TEMP_MSISDN/'$1'/g' | java_gcc_soap_any.ksh
```

Comment: `-i` makes no sense here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try things like:

```
printf '%s' "$s" | sed "s/TEMP_MSISDN/$1/g" | java_gcc_soap_any.ksh
```

but that is very fragile.  If `$1` contains `/`, for instance, this will fail.  You can try to fix that with things like:

```
printf '%s' "$s" | sed "s@TEMP_MSISDN@$1@g" | java_gcc_soap_any.ksh
```

but you're just trading one bad symbol for another and not really making the solution robust.  If you are using `bash`, you can also try things like:

```
printf '%s' "${s/TEMP_MSISDN/$1}" | java_gcc_soap_any.ksh
```